# CSS - dynamic menu image

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm planning a website and wondering what the best way to create the following item is in CSS:

[image: Menu bar]

I want a triangle to appear beneath an item in the menu bar, but the horizontal position of the triangle will change depending on which page the user is currently on (it will highlight the currently viewing menu item)

Is there a way to do this dynamic positioning with just CSS?

Comment: You would have to make a helper CSS class like `active` that would display the arrow under the menu item. But you would have to set this active class via javascript or some server side code. CSS has no way of knowing which page is active.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is download Bootstrap, and create a >div element for your navbar, which you probably already have. Then you need to identify each list item in all your navbar pages as >active, so it gets similar highlights to that of what you want.

To add triangles, you'll need a special CSS class or a downloaded theme.